# How to prevent copying of the image folder of your website

Tags: security

How to Prevent copying of the original image folder when the entire website is being copied. Also,what are the measures that should be taken to prevent guessing of the original images.

Comment: If the images are linked in your site, you don't need to be able to guess it. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes the image folder contain all images shown in website and even the watermark image .And i dont to prevent any one /software from copying it.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the original (i.e. non watermarked) images in a non-public folder, inaccessible from the web. When someone want to buy an image, send him using another way, like a CD-ROM.

The alternative is to serve the original images using a dynamic web app, which verifies that the logged-in user has the right to download the image, fetches the image from a protected folder, and then streams it to the HTTP response.

Comment: I think you didnt got the problem correctly.I want the tools to be forbidden to copy my folders in my project specially image folder

Comment: Everything put on the web is downloadable. If it weren't, the browser could not download the image to display it. If you don't want your images to be downloaded, don't put them on a web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent it completely. Custom-build web crawlers can always analyze your site and get the image urls, just like any legit browsers. The best you can do is to detect large amount of access from the same IP, and block that ip when it reaches certain number of hits per minutes.

You can also probably prevent hot-linking by checking the http referrer. This however can be faked by crawlers too.